# Default and Custom dates in one Date Slicer filter with no Extra button

Tags: filter, powerbi, dax, powerquery, business-intelligence

In my dashboard, I have a date slicer that has my date column in it. I need my report to show Current Month data information by default and also i want user to be able to select any date range that available in my date column.

I could get this done with an extra button such as "Default" & "Custom" types and filter out that way, but my user doensn't want any other button or extra date slicer.

It has to be done in one date slicer that can show current month data by default and able to customize it whenever date range (For this case min available date is 01-01-2020 till today)

So far i created a new table with below query but i think this solution also requires another date slicer or button. Can someone help me please and thanks for now

Date Periods =
UNION(
ADDCOLUMNS(
DATESBETWEEN('rpt date'[Date], STARTOFMONTH('rpt date'[Date]), TODAY()),
"Type", "Default"),
ADDCOLUMNS(
CALENDAR(MIN('rpt date'[Date]),MAX('rpt date'[Date])),
"Type", "Custom"
)
)

Comment: Note: I already tried filter it with relative date> In This Month but when i select "in this month" option then this filter will be no longer customizable.

Comment: There is no way to set a "default" dynamic custom selection in slicer at this time.

Comment: This is such a simple and needed option. Why would they missed it?

Comment: it is in the backlog, it has been for some time now..
https://ideas.fabric.microsoft.com/ideas/idea/?ideaid=39ba67cf-724e-4b6c-9906-51163749f759

Comment: anyone, any other suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I also have similar requirement and have created a column in calendar table with below option
Default = IF('Dim Calendar'[date]<=TODAY() && 'Dim Calendar'[date] >= TODAY()-7, "Last 7 Days", "Custom")